# append key's value on same key

Tags: python, json, mongodb

This is what I currently have

code

```
coll = con['X']['Y']
s = "meta http equiv"

m = {'i': s}
n = json.dumps(m)
o = json.loads(n)
coll.insert(o)
```

data

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("58527fe656c7a95cfaf40a15"), 
    "i" : "meta http equiv"
}
```

Now in the next iteration, `s` will change(as per my computations) and I want to append the value of `s` to same key

let's say in next iteration s becomes `sample test data and` on same key `i`

So I want this

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("58527fe656c7a95cfaf40a15"), 
    "i" : "meta http equiv sample test data and"
}
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change the way you have formed s:

```
s = "meta http equiv"
s = (coll.get('i', '') + ' ' + s) if coll.get('i', '') else s
```

If coll isn't a dict object use [getattr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=getattr#getattr) instead:

```
s = "meta http equiv"
s = (getattr(coll, 'i', '') + ' ' + s) if getattr(coll, 'i', '') else s
```

Comment: sorry but which library has this module `call`?

Comment: i am getting error `TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'get' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.
`

Comment: @Guru, What is the type of `coll` ? also you can try: replace `coll.get('i', '')` to `getattr(coll, 'i', '')`

Comment: `coll` is of type `<class 'pymongo.collection.Collection'>
`

Comment: Now I am getting `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Collection' and 'str'
`